# "Корень слова". Первичное или вторичное значение слова "корень"?

Tags: значение-слов

Первичное или вторичное значение слова "корень" в словосочетании "корень слова"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Главное значение слова КОРЕНЬ - вросшая в землю часть растения, через которую оно всасывает соки из почвы. Это первичное значение слова.
Корень слова - это главная часть слова без приставок и суффиксов. Вторичное значение слова КОРЕНЬ, но у того и  другого есть в значениии общее - основа, главное, то, от чего идёт "наращение".

Comment: А как вы трактуете первичное и вторичное значение?  
Если я правильно понимаю, тут уместно говорить об первом и втором (или основном и второстепенных значениях), а первичное и вторичное - это когда одно является причиной возникновение другого, т.е. выросло из другого или развилось из употребления первого в переносном смысле. Нет?  
Здесь я как-то не очень понимаю, как один корень мог стать причиной названия другого...

Answer (score 2):

Оба значения слова являются следствием перевода многочисленных потомков 
латинского морфа "radi" - круговой и т.п. Эта латинская основа в разных языках развилась в разные значения,  одно из которых - "извлекать". Это-то "извлекать" и является сближающим значением (совсем не "основа") для обоих рассматриваемых значений слова "корень". (Есть еще третий, математический, он очень близок к филологическому, я их объединяю).
Но эти два значения появились в языке совершенно независимо друг от друга, среди них нет "первичного и вторичного", есть "первое и второе" или "основное и второстепенное". 
Поэтому я бы остановился на той формулировке, что ***первое*** значение - корень ботанический, ***второе*** - лингвистический. 
(+)
Если я не ошибаюсь, в латинском оба корня - radix. Поэтому наш второй, лингвистический, корень можно считать своего рода калькой с латинского: когда это слово понадобилось филологам, они просто перевели на русский омонимичное латинское слово - т.е. "ботанической" корень.
Попробую уточнить. Даже если дело не совсем так обстояло, все сказанное выше - в силе.